# OSX Remove Ruby and Gems Manually

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I am a new OSX convert :) Just putting that out there lol.

I have installed XAMPP, ruby (with a hand full of gems), homebrew, gulp, bower, and many other dev things since I got this mac. To my admittance, I didn't know what I was doing. I have done this all on Windows for years, but Mac and the HD paths, are a different ball game. I would just wipe the drive and re-install it like the day I bought it, but my wife also has an account on here and I would like to not do that.

Because of homebrew, I (stupidly) allowed it to change permissions and ownership of my `/usr/local` directory. I recently read that it is a bad mistake (even though homebrew docs recommend it!), and that I can actually define the path somewhere else, like my own User directory. From my reading, `/usr/local` isn't required for my Mac to run, and it is left there as a standard, but many tools use this directory/path. I did notice however, that Avast had a link to a `scan` script in there. Weird, but that is the only non-developer file I noticed in there.

I booted into recovery mode and deleted the `/usr/local` directory and remade it using `chflags norestricted "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/local"` so now I have a brand new local dir. However, nothing is in it anymore (which I expected). So now I am cleaning up the mess.

Ruby installs gems into the `/usr/local/bin` directory, which they are all gone, but ruby still thinks they are there. How can I tell ruby to uninstall these, when they are missing?

I actually was getting permission denied, but the `bin` directory doesn't exist either. Basically Ruby has a list somewhere of gems installed as an index, but the actual files are missing. I need to clear the list, or force and uninstall all and ignore any errors. Then lastly, uninstall Ruby.

Honestly, I am trying to uninstall everything dev related on here, and start again. I am pretty close, just cleaning up some stragglers.

**FWIW:** I tried various commands, including using `sudo` with them:

`gem uninstall <name>`

`gem uninstall --all`

`` for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done ``

and a few others, but I am left with a few gems, and Ruby still thinks they are there, and they aren't because `/usr/local/bin` doesn't even exist and `/usr/local` is completely empty (because I reset it and started over)

**PS:** Additionally, if someone knows how to properly reset the `/usr/local` directory and file permissions back to a stock El Capitan, that would be great. I am not sure if I did it right, or how to check that the permissions are correct. I plan on going to my dad's house and looking at his, his is stock and an identical MBP.

**CURRENT RUBY GEMS**
This is the list I have. I am posting it just in case I am missing a bunch after my escapade. Maybe you can compare them to yours (or a stock list of gems)

```
MacBook-Pro:local work$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
commander (4.4.0)
httpclient (2.7.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rhc (1.38.4)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

Machine: Macbook Pro Retina mid 2015 model running El Capitan 10.11.5 (15F34)

Comment: Are you sure you're not just picking up the version of ruby that is shipped with OS X (which includes a few gems) ?

Comment: No, I am not sure it wasn't the OSX packaged ruby. I just ran `which ruby` and got `/usr/bin/ruby`. What gems are installed by default on OSX? I hope I didn't uninstall them lol.

Answer (score 1):

OSX 10.10.5:

```
/usr$ ls -ald local
drwxrwxr-x  27 root  admin  918 Apr 25 19:35 local

/usr$ ls -alOd local
drwxrwxr-x  27 root  admin  - 918 Apr 25 19:35 local
```

> Then lastly, uninstall Ruby.

Don't uninstall the system Ruby, i.e. the Ruby that came with your computer.  Instead, install your own Ruby.  I suggest you just abandon the Ruby that's giving you trouble: if it's a Ruby you installed, then install rvm(for managing multiple ruby installations), then install a different ruby version and set that as the default in rvm.  rvm installs Rubies into your Users directory.  Also, once you have rvm installed, NEVER use sudo to install gems.

The general rule is: don't start deleting things when something goes wrong: most likely you will never track down all the rabbit holes where files were installed. In any case, always ask before you start deleting stuff--then you can get suggestions for an alternate course of action.

Comment: I agree with your general rule. I did a lot of Googling trying to make the most logical decisions. There is no better way to learn a new system than to just dive in and not be scared to break it. After all, I can just boot into recovery and magically set it back to the day I bought it :) -- @l'L'l I believe those permissions and `root:wheel` are on newer OSX versions with SIP. In my case, I am on the latest El Capitan.

Comment: I added my `gem list` output to my question. Maybe someone could compare them to ensure I am not missing a bunch of necessary ones this machine came with.